# node.js protecting DB credentials

Tags: node.js, database, permissions

If you go here:
http://armygrounds.com/jsgame/server.js

It's publicly visible and anyone could get the DB credentials.

How do I prevent this? Is it a file permission setting?

Comment: Your code and/or configuration is mistakenly making your server code available.   You need to fix your server code so that it does not expose ANY of your server code/configuration to the public.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is an issue with your webserver configuration. You should not expose your nodejs source to the web. In this case, you want to move the server side code out of the location that is visible from the website. You probably want to set up your web server to proxy to nodejs when it needs to be called.

Its a little difficult to answer your question more accurately without knowing more of your setup.

Comment: So in a sense you put it outside of the /var/www/html or /usr/share/nginx/html then? Correct? So that way running "npm start" would just call it from a not accessible directory anywhere on your server.

Comment: Correct. Server side code should always be outside of the location made public by your web server. You could use /var/www/nodejs for example, if your nginx root is /var/www/html